# How can I calculate the GAP between two products from different tables and with a set of conditions?

Tags: powerbi, dax, price

I'm relatively new around the world of Power BI. I've got two different types of diesel, each of them with different prices.

I've also got calculated Moving Averages of both, and I need to see the average GAP between them but under the condition they need to have a value in the same DAY to calculate such average, otherwise it wouldn't be valid. The tables and expected result is kind of as follows:

TABLE DIESEL TYPE A

| Date | Price DIESEL TYPE A |
| --- | --- |
| 01-feb | 1,2 |
| 05-may | 1,3 |
| 06-ago | 1,09 |
| 06-ago | 1,1 |
| 07-sep | 1,5 |

TABLE DIESEL TYPE B

| Date | Price DIESEL TYPE B |
| --- | --- |
| 01-feb | 0,9 |
| 05-may | 1,05 |
| 06-ago | 0,8 |
| 06-ago | 0,75 |
| 12-nov | 0,7 |

| Date | Average A | Average B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-feb | 1,2 | 0,9 |
| 05-may | 1,3 | 1,05 |
| 06-ago | 1,095 | 0,775 |
| 07-sep | 1,5 | - |
| 12-nov | - | 0,7 |

The expected GAP should be:

| Date | GAP Average |
| --- | --- |
| 01-feb | 0,30 |
| 05-may | 0,25 |
| 06-ago | 0,32 |
| 07-sep | - |
| 12-nov | - |

In September 7th and November 12th I DONT want to have these averages calculated or shown on my graph, i.e. on my measure.

Getting an average of the difference between these two prices by date and under the condition there should be values for the same date in both type of diesels, otherwise I don't want to calculate such average, if for instance, there's a value 07-sep for Type A but no for Type B, and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

Use this measure:

```
GAP Average = 
VAR avgA = 
    AVERAGE('DIESEL TYPE A'[Price DIESEL TYPE A])
VAR avgB = 
    AVERAGE('DIESEL TYPE B'[Price DIESEL TYPE B])
RETURN
    IF(
        OR(ISBLANK(avgA), ISBLANK(avgB)),
        BLANK(),
        avgA - avgB
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Did the answer help to solve your problem?